# My crontab script won't run

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in sd{a..n}; do echo $arg; smartctl --all --json --nocheck standby /dev/$arg > /root/smartctl/$arg.json; done
```

If I run the script from the command line it works perectly

```
root@server:~/smartctl# bash update.sh
```

However when I run via crobtab -e it doesn't work

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /root/smartctl/update.sh
```

When it is run by crontab it just creates a bunch of empty files (/tmp/sda.json etc)
When I run via terminal it creates those files, but they are not empty files.

My OS is ubuntu 18.04 lts

Comment: Is your script called `smartcl` or `update.sh`, and when you say you run `~/smartctl` [this runs] but this `* * * * * /bin/bash /root/smartctl/update.sh` doesn't. Those two last commands aren't the same... Please reword your question.

Answer (score 1):

`smartctl` should be `/usr/sbin/smartctl`

Comment: And exactly should this change be made?